# Unexpected NHibernate Get behavior

Tags: nhibernate

I have a brown-field application with 5 domain objects: CreditMemo, CreditMemoDetail, SalesInvoice, ReceivablesRecord, TransactionType. CreditMemo is one--many with CreditMemoDetail. It is also many-to-one with SalesInvoice. SalesInvoice is one-to-many with ReceivablesRecord which is many to one with TransactionType (xml mapping below). None of the relationships depend upon any values outside of their direct parent/child.

When I perform a Get(id), I get the entire structure back correctly: The columns from CreditMemo are properly filled out, the ISet is correct, and the entire SalesInvoice/ReceivablesRecord/TransactionType hierarchy is fully populated. When I perform a Get(invoiceNumber), the SalesInvoice object is filled correctly but the ISet is empty. Using NHProfiler, the exact same queries are executed, including the parameters. I've been knocking this one around for hours now and haven't been able to come up with anything that makes sense.

I know that I can brute force things but the fact that the relationships work automagically when starting with a CreditMemo but not when starting with a SalesInvoice is driving me nuts. Any ideas?

Objects and Mappings:

```
public class CreditMemo
{
    public virtual int CreditMemoId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreditMemoNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreditDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string ReturnToStock { get; set; }
    public virtual string Posted { get; set; }
    public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<CreditMemoDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesInvoice InvoiceInfo { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" schema="aladdin" namespace="Receivables.Models">
  <class name="Receivables.Models.CreditMemo, Receivables" lazy="false" table="credit_memo">
    <id name="CreditMemoId" column="credit_memo_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="InvoiceNumber" column="invoice_no" />
    <property name="CreditMemoNumber" column="credit_memo_no" />
    <property name="CreditDate" column="credit_date" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="ReturnToStock" column="return_to_stock" />
    <property name="Posted" column="posted" />
    <property name="Notes" column="notes" />
    <many-to-one name="InvoiceInfo" class="SalesInvoice" column="invoice_no" update="false" insert="false" />
    <set name="Details" cascade="delete">
      <key column="credit_memo_id" />
      <one-to-many class="CreditMemoDetail"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class CreditMemoDetail
{
    public virtual int CreditMemoDetailId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CreditMemoId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreditType { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual string AffectCommission { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" schema="aladdin" namespace="Receivables.Models">
  <class name="Receivables.Models.CreditMemoDetail, Receivables" lazy="false" table="cr_memo_detail">
    <id name="CreditMemoDetailId" column="crmemodetailid">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="CreditMemoId" column="credit_memo_id" />
    <property name="CreditType" column="credit_type" />
    <property name="Amount" column="amount" />
    <property name="AffectCommission" column="affect_commission" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class SalesInvoice
{
    public virtual string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual string ClassOfSale { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<ReceivablesRecord> Transactions { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" schema="aladdin" namespace="Receivables.Models">
  <class name="Receivables.Models.SalesInvoice, Receivables" lazy="false" table="invoice">
    <id name="InvoiceNumber" column="invoice_no">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="Customer" column="customer" />
    <property name="InvoiceDate" column="invoice_date" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="SalesPerson" column="salesman" />
    <property name="ClassOfSale" column="class" />
    <set name="Transactions">
      <key column="invoice_no" />
      <one-to-many class="ReceivablesRecord"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class ReceivablesRecord
{
    public virtual string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AccrecDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string TxType { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionType TypeInfo { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            ReceivablesRecord input = (ReceivablesRecord)obj;
            if (InvoiceNumber == input.InvoiceNumber && AccrecDate == input.AccrecDate && TxType == input.TxType)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", InvoiceNumber, AccrecDate, TxType).GetHashCode();
    }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" schema="aladdin" namespace="Receivables.Models">
  <class name="Receivables.Models.ReceivablesRecord, Receivables" lazy="false" table="accrec">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="InvoiceNumber" column="invoice_no" />
      <key-property name="AccrecDate" column="accrec_date" type="DateTime" />
      <key-property name="TxType" column="tx_type" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Amount" column="amount" />
    <property name="Note" column="note" />
    <many-to-one name="TypeInfo" class="TransactionType" column="tx_type" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class TransactionType
{
    public virtual string TransactionCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal GLAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Taxable { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" schema="aladdin" namespace="Receivables.Models">
  <class name="Receivables.Models.TransactionType, Receivables" lazy="false" table="txtype">
    <id name="TransactionCode" column="tx_code">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="Description" column="description" />
    <property name="GLAccountNumber" column="gl_account_no" type="Decimal" />
    <property name="Taxable" column="taxable" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Repository Code:

```
    public CreditMemo GetById(int id)
    {
        return NhSession.Get<CreditMemo>(id);
    }

    public SalesInvoice GetInvoiceByInvoiceNumber(string id)
    {
        SalesInvoice salesInvoice = NhSession.Get<SalesInvoice>(id);
        return salesInvoice;
    }
```

Alternate GetInvoiceByInvoiceNumber which *does* work (i.e., it returns all the levels of detail below SalesInvoice without changes to the mappings):

```
    return NhSession.CreateQuery("from SalesInvoice where InvoiceNumber = :invoice_no")
        .SetString("invoice_no", id).UniqueResult<SalesInvoice>();
```

Comment: "When I perform a Get(id)," - what type, what id?

Comment: "When I perform a Get(invoiceNumber)" - I assume you mean Get<SalesInvoice>(invoiceNumber) here?

Comment: "correctly but the ISet is empty" - which set?

Comment: @Oskar I was being brief in the descriptions of my Get's - the actual code is at the bottom.  <br/>1. NhSession.Get<CreditMemo>(int id);  <br/>2. NhSession.Get<SalesInvoice>(string id).  <br/>3. SalesInvoice.Transactions. There is no mapping from SalesInvoice to CreditMemo so I expect nothing there and consequently in CreditMemo.Details.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no solution so far, but to be frank, the GetHashCode() implementation is horrible: It could be called often so it should not use a heavy method like string.Format(). That method also causes memory allocations, which should also be avoided for performance. Another problem is that it relies on the current culture for date formatting, which may cause the same or "similar" objects to generate different hash codes on different threads if they run with different culture settings.

Comment: @Oskar Fair enough. This is my first composite key mapping. Given that I have 2 string values and a date with which to work, do you have suggestions for how to improve it (besides addressing the culture issue on dates)?

Answer (score 0):

the Equals method of ReceivablesRecord can be the problem, change it to

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    ReceivablesRecord other = obj as ReceivablesRecord;
    return other != null &&
           InvoiceNumber == input.InvoiceNumber &&
           AccrecDate == input.AccrecDate &&
           TxType == input.TxType;
}
```

Comment: Same result. FWIW I'm pretty sure that our Equals methods are functionally equivalent but yours is more concise and elegant.